# hashCode() и equals() и мои примеры

Tags: java

Прочитал статью на Хабре и вот мои примеры и информация оттуда:

Мой код:

```
public class Man {

    private String noseSize;
    private String eyesColor;
    private String haircut;
    private boolean scars;
    private int dnaCode;

    public Man(String noseSize, String eyesColor, String haircut, boolean scars, int dnaCode) {
        this.noseSize = noseSize;
        this.eyesColor = eyesColor;
        this.haircut = haircut;
        this.scars = scars;
        this.dnaCode = dnaCode;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Man man = (Man) o;
        return dnaCode == man.dnaCode;
    }
//геттеры сеттеры и тд
```

Сперва, что-бы избежать путаницы, определимся с терминологией. Одинаковые объекты — это объекты одного класса с одинаковым содержимым полей.

> для одного и того-же объекта, хеш-код всегда будет одинаковым;

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Man man1 = new Man("Большой", "Зеленый", "Горшок", true, 13);
        Man man2 = new Man("Большой", "Зеленый", "Горшок", true, 13);
        System.out.println(man1.hashCode());
    }
}
```

Окей здесь всё правильно и сколько раз перезапускал показывает один и тот же хеш код, идем дальше:

> если объекты одинаковые, то и хеш-коды одинаковые

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Man man1 = new Man("Большой", "Зеленый", "Горшок", true, 13);
        Man man2 = new Man("Большой", "Зеленый", "Горшок", true, 13);
        System.out.println(man1.hashCode() + "  " + man2.hashCode());
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоль: `1802598046  659748578`
Почему здесь и два одинаковых хеш кода?
Идем дальше:

> если хеш-коды равны, то входные объекты не всегда равны (коллизия)

Это к сожалению я в данный момент не знаю как получить два одинаковых хеш кода, поэтому не смог проверить. Не буду против от примера.

> если хеш-коды разные, то и объекты гарантированно разные;
>   Еще раз возвращаюсь к этому примеру где хеш коды были разными, но объекты идентично одинаковые, вот что вывелось в консоль:

```
1802598046  659748578



 public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Man man1 = new Man("Большой", "Зеленый", "Горшок", true, 13);
            Man man2 = new Man("Большой", "Зеленый", "Горшок", true, 13);
            System.out.println(man1.hashCode() + "  " + man2.hashCode());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вас тут все равно немного запутали

> для одного и того-же объекта, хеш-код всегда будет одинаковым;

по умолчанию `hashCode` возвращает одинаковое значение для **одних и тех же** объектов но не для **одинаковых** объектов.

Это Вы сами с собой договорились что хотите чтобы идентичные объекты считались одним и тем же объектом и для этого соответствующим образом должны переопределить `equals` и `hashCode`, тогда поведение будет такое, как описано в статье, которую Вы читаете.

Если почитать [javadoc к методу hashcode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) то можно узнать что обычно, hashcode это адрес объекта в куче, приведенный к целому числу(Integer)

> As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by
>   class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This
>   is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the
>   object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not
>   required by the JavaTM programming language.)

Это достаточно важно, если учесть что эти методы (`equals()` и `hashСode()`) используются повсеместно внутри например Java коллекций, для того чтобы определить эквивалентность объектов. Причем крайне важно обеспечить хорошую функцию `hashСode()`, в противном случае возможны нежелательные коллизии.например с плохой функцией `hashСode()` объекты внутри `HashMap` будут чаще попадать в одну корзину, чем ухудшают общую производительность поиска по ключу в этой  `HashMap`, хоть и есть встроенный механизм защиты от этого

**`jdk1.8.0_131\src.zip!\java\util\HashMap.java`**

```
/**
 * Computes key.hashCode() and spreads (XORs) higher bits of hash
 * to lower.  Because the table uses power-of-two masking, sets of
 * hashes that vary only in bits above the current mask will
 * always collide. (Among known examples are sets of Float keys
 * holding consecutive whole numbers in small tables.)  So we
 * apply a transform that spreads the impact of higher bits
 * downward. There is a tradeoff between speed, utility, and
 * quality of bit-spreading. Because many common sets of hashes
 * are already reasonably distributed (so don't benefit from
 * spreading), and because we use trees to handle large sets of
 * collisions in bins, we just XOR some shifted bits in the
 * cheapest possible way to reduce systematic lossage, as well as
 * to incorporate impact of the highest bits that would otherwise
 * never be used in index calculations because of table bounds.
 */
static final int hash(Object key) {
    int h;
    return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
}
```

---

В Вашем примере

```
 Man man1 = new Man("Большой", "Зеленый", "Горшок", true, 13);
 Man man2 = new Man("Большой", "Зеленый", "Горшок", true, 13);
```

объекты идентичные по составу свойств, но разные их экземпляры (как братья-близнецы)

Если переопределить `equals()` и `hashСode()` соответствующим образом то такие объекты будут считаться одним объектом.

```
public class Man {

    private String noseSize;
    private String eyesColor;
    private String haircut;
    private boolean scars;
    private int dnaCode;

    public Man(String noseSize, String eyesColor, String haircut, boolean scars, int dnaCode) {
        this.noseSize = noseSize;
        this.eyesColor = eyesColor;
        this.haircut = haircut;
        this.scars = scars;
        this.dnaCode = dnaCode;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Man man = (Man) o;

        if (scars != man.scars) return false;
        if (dnaCode != man.dnaCode) return false;
        if (noseSize != null ? !noseSize.equals(man.noseSize) : man.noseSize != null) return false;
        if (eyesColor != null ? !eyesColor.equals(man.eyesColor) : man.eyesColor != null) return false;
        return haircut != null ? haircut.equals(man.haircut) : man.haircut == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = noseSize != null ? noseSize.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (eyesColor != null ? eyesColor.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (haircut != null ? haircut.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (scars ? 1 : 0);
        result = 31 * result + dnaCode;
        return result;
    }
}
```

---

PS: В приличных IDE есть функция, которая помогает сгенерировать этот код.

я пользуюсь **IntellijIdea community**, там это делается `Alt+Insert` > `equals() and hashCode()`